# 0.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am attempting to create a discord.js bot. The way it is set up, is I have a folder containing all the commands, and when a command is called, index.js sorts it to the right file. While attempting to run the bot, I get this error

`DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body`
`0.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required`

My error is not giving me what variable is undefined, and I can't find any sources to help me with the second line.

```
    require("dotenv").config();
    
    const { token } = process.env;
    const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
    const fs = require("fs");
    
    const client = new Client({ intents: GatewayIntentBits.Guilds });
    client.commands = new Collection();
    client.commandArray = [];
    
    const functionFolders = fs.readdirSync(`./functions`);
    console.log(`Has reached declaring functionFolders. Value: ${functionFolders}`)
    for (const folder of functionFolders) {
      console.log(`Folders: ${folder}`)
      const functionFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./functions/${folder}`).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
        console.log(`Has reached declaring Folder. functionFiles: ${functionFiles}`)
      for (const file of functionFiles)
        require(`./functions/${folder}/${file}`)(client);
      
    
    }
    client.handleCommands();
    client.handleEvents();
    client.login("This is my actual token, no peaking")
```

My index.js goes through every folder, then through every file that ends with .js, and I believe sends necessary information/commands to it.

I have `handleCommands`, `handleFunctions`, `interactionCreate`, and `ready` as my files that help the bot run.

```
    Has reached declaring functionFolders. Value: handlers
    Folders: handlers
    Has reached declaring Folder. functionFiles: handleCommands.js,handleEvents.js
    Command: ping has been processed.
    Started refreshing application (/) commands.
    Hint: hit control+c anytime to enter REPL.
    (node:90) ExperimentalWarning: stream/web is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
    (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
    DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
    0.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
        at SequentialHandler.runRequest (/home/runner/NewDiscordBot/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/lib/handlers/SequentialHandler.cjs:287:15)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
        at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (/home/runner/NewDiscordBot/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/lib/handlers/SequentialHandler.cjs:99:14)
        at async REST.request (/home/runner/NewDiscordBot/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/lib/REST.cjs:52:22) {
      rawError: {
        code: 50035,
        errors: { '0': [Object] },
        message: 'Invalid Form Body'
      },
      code: 50035,
      status: 400,
      method: 'PUT',
      url: 'https://discord.com/api/v9/applications/1002762316259012648/commands',
      requestBody: { files: undefined, json: [ [Object], [Object] ] }
    }
    Nyxx#3574 is online.
     
    (To exit, press Ctrl+C again or Ctrl+D or type .exit)
```

This is my Console after it is run, and towards the middle is where the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. In my second error, you see the method giving the error is `.put()` I changed this to `.push()` and those errors did not pop up again